# how to convert the customised time to seconds in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am looking for a solution for my issue. My issue is , i want to convert my data to seconds. The data in my HIVE table looks below:

my input :

```
        time
        2m3s
        10s
        12.2
        10
```

my expected output is

```
    time
    123
    10
    12.2
    10
```

if the value coming as 2m3s (2 minutes and 3 seconds) i need to convert to 2*60+3 seconds. if it is coming as 10s, then it means its in seconds i can take 10 and so on.

can someone help me how to achieve the same in hive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
select (case when time like '%m%s'
             then cast(regexp_extract(time, '^[0-9]+') as decimal(10, 2)) * 60 +
                  cast(replace(regexp_extract(time, '[0-9]+s$'), 's', '') as decimal(10, 2), 1)
             when time like '%s'
                  cast(replace(regexp_extract(time, '[0-9]+s$'), 's', '') as decimal(10, 2), 1)
             else cast(regexp_extract(time, '[0-9]+s$') as decimal(10, 2))
        end) as seconds
```

Comment: wonder how this worked..this is invalid syntax for `regexp_extract` in Hive

Comment: ya i have made it as valid syntax... but i haven't had the idea which is mentioned as above... i have corrected syntax and working fine now

Answer (score 1):

With `regexp_extract` and `regexp`. Note that this query only handles the two patterns shown. You might have to extend it based on other patterns in your data.

```
select case when time regexp '^[0-9]+[mM][0-9]+[sS]$' 
            then regexp_extract(time,'(^[0-9]+)',1) * 60 + regexp_extract(time,'([0-9]+)[sS]$',1)  
            when time regexp '^[0-9]+[sS]$' then regexp_extract(time,'([0-9]+)[sS]$',1)
       else time end
from tbl
```